# Digits of a number between 0 and 1.

Tags: binary

I'm currently working on a problem that requires me to know, for some $x=.x_1x_2x_3....x_n \in [0,1]$, when the $nth$ digit is equal to $0$ or $1$, in base $2.$ For example the interval where $x_1 = 1$ in base $2$ is $[\frac{1}{2}, 1)$, I think. And $x_2=1$ between $0$ and $\frac{1}{4}$ and also between $\frac{3}{4}$ and $1$. But when the $n$ gets larger, I feel that I should use some kind of pattern, but I'm not sure what to do.

I would like to do the same thing for the numbers in $[0,1]$ in base three.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The region where the $n$th digit in base $b$ takes on a particular value consists of $b^{n-1}$ disjoint intervals. Each of these has a particular sequence of values of all of the first $n$ digits.

Comment: You are mistaken with $x_2$: it should be $x_2 = 1$ when $x \in (\frac14, \frac12)$, not $(0, \frac14)$.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks. Is there some kind of quick way that I can find the intervals? So far, it's a little tedious, I'm not sure if there's a better way.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x$ be the number.

Is the integer part of $2^n x$ odd or even?

If it's odd, the $n$th bit after the binary point is $1$.

If it's even, the $n$th bit after the binary point is $0$.

If you're not convinced, try multiplying a  decimal number by $10^n$ and looking at the last digit of its integer part. Then remember that an even binary number ends in $0$.

Multiplying $x$ by $2^n$ just shifts its binary representation to the left by $n$ places.

Dividing by $2^n$ again, your intervals will be based on odd and even multiples of $2^{-n}$.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a picture is worth 1000 words.

Regions represented by a $1$ in successive digit places

**base 2**

[image]

**base 3**

[image]

Comment: Would there be a systematic way for me to find these intervals on my own? I've been simply converting numbers to base 2/base 3 and checking if I need to go up or down to get the digit to be of the value I want. So, I've just been guessing and checking. Is there a more efficient method?

Comment: See if you can infer the principle from my figures....

Comment: I was looking at the figures but I thought that for base 3, the region where the $nth$ digit takes a particular value is given by $3^{n-1}$ intervals. Shouldn't there be three intervals for $x_2$ on the second picture? I am missing something.

Comment: You are missing something.  There are three regions for the first digit, corresponding the the value being $0$, $1$ or $2$.  Only one is shown in my figure (for $1$); the region for $0$ is to the left, and for $2$ is to the right.  For the second digit, there are .... (can you continue?)....

Comment: I'm not sure. It looks like for the second digit, there is a region shown that has four intervals for a given value.

Comment: You were right.  Thanks for catching the typo.  Now (I think!) fixed.